# What does Vim create the ~/.vim/swap directory for?

Tags: vim, swap

I've noticed that Vim on my machine always creates the `~/.vim/swap` directory on startup. I can't find any reference about it in the docs. Also, I have this setting in my `.vimrc`:

```
set directory^=~/.vim/tmp//  " where to store swap files
```

What is the `~/.vim/swap` directory created for?

Comment: Are you using NeoVim? NeoVim will auto-create swap file directory based [off of `'directory'`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#'directory').

Comment: @Peter Good to know, but I'm using Vim 8.0. Anyway, it turned out the directory was being created in one of the system's vimrc files (see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49074314/275088))

Answer (score 2):

It turned out my system vimrc contained this:

```
" Move the swap file location to protect against CVE-2017-1000382
if ! isdirectory('~/.vim/swap/')
  silent! call system('install -dm 700 ~/.vim/swap')
endif
set directory=~/.vim/swap/
```

That's why the directory was being re-created each time I was starting Vim.